# Generated SQL query with "WHERE (1 <> 1)" condition

Tags: postgresql, go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I'm trying to query a many-to-many relationship using the [Gorm ORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) for Go.

I have two structs: `User` & `Address`.

```
type User struct {
    // gorm.Model
    UUID        string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Firstname   string
    // ...

    Addresses []Address `gorm:"many2many:useraddresses"` 
}

// Address represents the Postgres SQL address model
type Address struct {
    UUID         string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Line1        string
    // ...
}
```

I took inspiration from the [many-to-many example shown here in the documentation](http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#many-to-many), (except I used a slice of users `[]User` instead of a single user).

```
var u []User
var a []Address
```

If I query just using the users as a Model, all users are returned (sends sql query `SELECT * FROM "users"`):

```
db.Model(&u).Find(&u)
```

However, if I include related Addresses, surgeons are returned, but no Addresses:

```
db.Model(&u).Related(&a, "Addresses").Find(&u)
```

This creates another sql query that precedes the first:

```
SELECT "addresses".* 
FROM "addresses" INNER JOIN "useraddresses" ON "useraddresses"."address_uuid" = "addresses"."uuid" 
WHERE (1 <> 1)
```

Of course, the `where false` condition prevents any addresses from being returned.

Can anyone shed light on how I can include the addresses using the `db.Model` method of Gorm?

Comment: I think you just want to do `db.Preload("Addresses").Find(&u)`

Comment: I've tried `Preload` and there are some side effects I'm trying to avoid.  Are there other ways to query many-to-many relationships, such as `Related`?